# Is it possbile to cover a win32 window with another transparent window without affecting user experience?

Tags: windows, winapi

let's take notepad.exe for example, is it possbile to create a same size transparent window on top of notepad main window without affecting user experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possbile to create a same size transparent window on top of notepad main window

It is pretty easy to `FindWindow()` the Notepad window, then `GetWindowRect()` its position and dimensions, and then place your custom window at the same location and size.  You can use the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style with `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` or `UpdateLayeredWindow()` to apply transparency/translucency to your window as needed.

Or, you might consider creating a layered window as a direct child of Notepad's window (Windows 8+ only), see:

[Creating a Transparent Child window on top of non-transparent Parent Window ( win 32 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513716/)

> without affecting user experience?

Not so easily, no. You might be tempted to use the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` window style, but be aware that [WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is a lie, or at least not the entire truth](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121217-00/?p=5823) ([also this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111028-00/?p=9243)).  Or you might be tempted to handle `WM_NCHITTEST` to return `HTTRANSPARENT`, but that [gets complicated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110218-00/?p=11453) ([also this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101230-00/?p=11873)).

Comment: *"then `GetWindowRect()` its position and dimensions"* - Sounds simple, right? Well, yes. If you are on Windows XP. With Vista and up you have to account for the DWM's idiosyncrasy of attributing a window's drop shadow area to the window area. Add several different kinds of DPI-awareness into the mix and you'll wind up with a complex implementation that frequently returns the wrong values nevertheless.