# Changing opacity of child window without using WS_EX_LAYERED

Tags: c++, winapi, opacity, hwnd

I have a window and then I create a child window using the following code:

```
HWND childHwnd = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_LAYERED, "Test", "Test", WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 500, 500, mainHwnd, NULL, instance, NULL);
```

After it has been created I can control the opacity using:

```
static COLORREF color = RGB(255, 0, 0);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(childHwnd, color, 127, LWA_ALPHA);
```

It works fine but I also have to support Windows 7 and MSDN says the following:

> Windows 8: The WS_EX_LAYERED style is supported for top-level windows and child windows. Previous Windows versions support WS_EX_LAYERED only for top-level windows.

I have installed Windows 7 in a VM and sadly it doesn't works. What could be the workaround to achieve the same opacity control over a child window in Windows 7?

I also tried to make it a standalone window and just follow the position of the parent window but the user experience is not that good when the window gets moved fast.

Comment: There's no "workaround", it's simply not supported. If you want a transparent effect from a child window on Windows 7 you'll need to render it that way yourself.

Comment: Little point trying to support an ancient OS like win 7. I mean, it's time to drop support for win 8.1 so win 7 should be long gone.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

[Using Layered Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-windows#using-layered-windows)

> In order to use layered child windows, the application has to declare itself Windows 8-aware in the manifest.

I suggest you refer to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42570249/11872808

In Windows 7, you could try to use the [`SetWindowRgn()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn).

I suggest you refer to this question:

[Creating a Transparent Child window on top of non-transparent Parent Window (win32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513716/)